# ModernAsyncTask IllegalStateException

Tags: android

We are using AsyncTaskLoaders in our app, to load the content. We are getting this crash

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.doInBackground(ModernAsyncTask.java:414)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.executePendingTask(AsyncTaskLoader.java:219)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnCancelled(AsyncTaskLoader.java:232)
   at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onCancelled(AsyncTaskLoader.java:88)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:464)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.access$400(ModernAsyncTask.java:48)
   at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:483)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

We have tried to reproduce this, but haven't been successful!

Is there a way to find out which Loader that is causing this?

We are using 
com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1

We are looking into the possibility that this might have a link to Activity Leaks, other than that, this is all the info we are getting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use yourtask.cancel event?

Comment: we are not calling cancel explicitly

Answer (score 2):

I'm still hunting this error as I can't reproduce it myself, but I believe I found the cause (at least for my case, but I have to release and see if it helps).

Turns out that when creating the observer on my loader I passed the handler as null, expecting similar beheavior as I would get if I use the default constructor for Handler (for it to run on the main thread, the thread I was creating it from).
However what happens is that it calls onChange inmediately, from whatever thread.. onChange at least in my case calls the loader's onContentChanged, that is documented to need to be called from the main thread... as that's not the case, the task and cancellationTask get screwed up (for lack of a better technical term) which causes the cancellation to be triggered in an unexpected state of the task, hence the error message.

This also manifested in my case as the loader not correctly updating entries, the cancellationTask was already loaded with a value, so the loader discarded new tasks, so the new load was skipped (takeContentChanged was false).

So make sure you are initializing your observer using new Handler() from the main thread (onStartLoading should be a fine place to do it).

Comment: I did release and it helped with the exception, at least I haven't seen it since :)

Answer (score 0):

Propably you have in your activity, or wrapper class reference to async task. If you have execution  of this task in onClick. You can tap two times on View and you get this error.

**Update**

If you want to check if activity has leaked , you can use Leak Canary. This is very useful tool.

[Leak canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

You can use StrictMode for finding information about leaks.

```
 public void onCreate() {
 if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
             .detectDiskReads()
             .detectDiskWrites()
             .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
             .penaltyLog()
             .build());
     StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
             .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
             .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
             .penaltyLog()
             .penaltyDeath()
             .build());
 }
 super.onCreate();
```

}

Comment: No, you are wrong. in that case you get: http://pastebin.com/mLs8Qu3e
AsyncTask have nothing to do with ModernAsyncTask which a loader is using.